# Select multiple top3 from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a database view. I have got table, which contains records about the peoples, which solved some logical examples during year and they got points for that.

I need to create view from SQL query, but I have got a problem - I need to get TOP 3 users per every year by one query.

```
SELECT solver, year, SUM(points) as TotalPoints
FROM solving
GROUP BY solver, year 
ORDER BY year, TotalPoints DESC
```

I got solvers per years sorted by points and year. I know I need to use limit, but I also know I will need one Select more, but I dont know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this in MySQL.  Probably the most efficient is to use variables.  The following enumerates the values:

```
SELECT yt.*,
       (@rn := if(@y = year, @rn + 1,
                  if(@y := year, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as seqnum
FROM (SELECT solver, year, SUM(points) as TotalPoints
      FROM solving
      GROUP BY solver, year
     ) yt CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @y := 0, @rn := 0) vars
ORDER BY year, TotalPoints DESC;
```

Then use this as a subquery to get the top three:

```
SELECT yt.*
FROM (SELECT yt.*,
             (@rn := if(@y = year, @rn + 1,
                        if(@y := year, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT solver, year, SUM(points) as TotalPoints
            FROM solving
            GROUP BY solver, year
           ) yt CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @y := 0, @rn := 0) vars
      ORDER BY year, TotalPoints DESC
     ) yt
WHERE seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this may help you out.

```
SELECT solver,
    year,
    SUM(points) AS TotalPoints
FROM (
    SELECT solver,
        year,
        SUM(points) AS TotalPoints
    FROM solving
    ORDER BY year,
        TotalPoints DESC
    )
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY year,
    TotalPoints DESC;
```